# get arraylist values in another method

Tags: java, arraylist, collections

This is the first time i'm using collection in java, here i need little guidance to retrieve combined arraylist object in another method.

//first method getData()

```
while(rs.next())
    {         
     fetchValue=new NewClass();

     fetchValue.setCount(rs.getInt(1));
     fetchValue.setIp(rs.getString(2));


     data.add(fetchValue);

    }
return data;
```

//second method get2Data()

```
while(rs.next())
    {         
     fetchValue1=new NewClass();

     fetchValue1.setCount(rs.getInt(1));
     fetchValue1.setIp(rs.getString(2));


     data1.add(fetchValue1);
    //System.out.println(data1);
    }
return data1;
```

//third method printValue()

```
Query_One printValue=new Query_One();
   printValue.get2Data();
   printValue.getData();
   List arr=new ArrayList();
   arr.add(data);
   arr.add(data1);
//i was trying following method but it doesn't working.. 
 //for(int i=0;i<arr.size();i++)
  //{
      //System.out.println(arr.get(i).getCount());
  //}
```

here how do i get Count and Ip values? and.. am i writing correct coding?
please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Collections in Java get a so called Generic to determine which methods you can call on the objects the collection is holding. In your Case you get the standard class as the Generic which would be Object (all classes except primitive datatypes extend from this class) so you can only call standards methods such as toString() or equals(). You should set the Generic for your List to your NewClass which would look something like this:

```
List<NewClass> myList = new ArrayList();//After Java 1.7 with Diamond interface (no brackets at the construction)
List<NewClass> myList = new ArrayList<NewClass>();//Pre Java 1.7 without Diamond interface
```

I hope this helps :)

EDIT: To make it a bit easier and without an index you could also use a for-each loop like this:

```
for(NewClass arrObject : arr){
    System.out.println(arrObject.getCount());
}
```

Comment: all three method are placed in the same class

Comment: oh i am sorry it had to be NewClass in the first brackets of the second line too. I will edit my answer...but yes i only have two lines because it changed in the java version 1.7 and i don´t exactly know which version you use. Just use one of the lines to initialize your List and you can call the methods of your class on the listobjects

Answer (score 0):

In your code you are trying to access the getCount() method on the arr.get(i), but that arr.get(i) is basically returning an object. So you have to cast it to NewClass as follows

```
for(int i=0;i<arr.size();i++)
{
    System.out.println(((NewClass)arr.get(i)).getCount());
}
```

Then you can access the getCount() method on it, as it will be called now on NewClass and not on Object.

Answer (score 0):

If you are adding list in another list, you should use `addAll`. 
`add` is to add single object in a list object.

change below code,

```
arr.add(data);
arr.add(data1);
```

to

```
arr.addAll(data);
arr.addAll(data1);
```